# Why does my array display does not add up?

Tags: c, loops

The variable named "stop" does not add up when displayed. It should be displayed "Input numbers for array 1 then 2...5".

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000 

void main(){
    int num[MAX_SIZE];
    printf("Input number of integers in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &num[MAX_SIZE]);
    
    for(size_t stop=0; stop<num[MAX_SIZE]; stop++){
        printf("\nInput numbers for array %d: ", num[stop]);
        scanf("%d", &num[stop]);
        

    }
}
```

[the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMhKe.png)

Comment: `scanf("%d", &num[MAX_SIZE]);` you are trying to write outside the bounds of an array. Overall, it's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here. Inside the loop why are you printing elements before you assign values to them?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to set the size of the array throughout runtime, on which case you should use dynamic memory allocation with `calloc` or `malloc` and remove the preprocessor directive.

Comment: This isn't how arrays work.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

1. Keep the preprocessor directive:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 10 

int main(){
    int num[MAX_SIZE];
    int i;
    
    for(i=0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++){
        printf("\nInput numbers for array %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2. Or, which is most likely what you are trying to do, use dynamic memory allocation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int *num;
    int i, maxSize;

    printf("Input number of integers in the array: ");
    scanf("%d", &maxSize);

    num = (int *)malloc(maxSize * sizeof(int)); // allocate dynamic memory
    
    for (i=0; i < maxSize; i++){
        printf("\nInput numbers for array %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num[i]);
    }

    free(num); // free pointer
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(int))`. As it is you are allocating enough memory for MAX_SIZE int pointers, rather than MAX_SIZE ints.

Comment: @Chris you are correct

Comment: Stylistically, `MAX_SIZE` is no more a preprocessor constant, and I suggest spelling it in lower cases. You forgot testing success of `scanf`  and of `malloc` - both could fail

Comment: I did the first and it worked. It seems that I just need to type the "stop" variable. Would you mind expaining how the malloc() and sizeof() works?